# What is the solubility of d-Glucose in water as a function of temperature?

Tags: organic-chemistry, solubility, solutions

I can't find solubility of d-Glucose in water as a function of temperature.

I.e. a function that can tell me that at 35 Celsius the maximum amount of d-Glucose that can be dissolved in 100g water is X

---

I presume that this publication has the answer, but I don't have access to it.

- Alves et al (2007) Solubility of d-Glucose in Water and Ethanol/Water Mixtures
- https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je700177n

Comment: Have you used Google Scholar (https://scholar.google.com) ? The very first result is your desired answer. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/je700177n.

Comment: I don't have access to that publication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a linear function of temperature (upto 60 C) as per this paper:
Solubility of d-Glucose in Water and Ethanol/Water Mixtures, . Chem. Eng. Data 2007, 52, 6, 2166-2170

[image]